# What happens when I reassign the mutable default argument inside a function?

Tags: python

I know this has been answered in highly active '[least astonishment' question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), I modified code snippet slightly but still don't understand why it produces new empty list and adds 1 to it..

```
def foo(var=[]):
    if len(var) == 0:
        var = []
    print(var)
    var.append(1)
    return var

print(foo())
print(foo())
```

outputs:

```
[]
[1]
[]
[1]
```

My expected logic of this python snippet:

- on the first call of foo(), var is initialized to empty list and indeed - **evaluated at definition of foo ONCE** - as the popular question answered.
- That if clause check should not be entered at all - because var is initialized only once, on the 2nd call foo() it should simply skip it and add 1 to var = [ 1 ] thus making the result [1,1] after the 2nd call.

But it does still go to if clause and init var to [] every time.. why?

However, if I remove the if clause:

```
def foo(var=[]):

    print(var)
    var.append(1)
    return var


print(foo())
print(foo())
```

It does append "1" to var every time and var grows:

```
[1]

[1,1]
```

So the if clause is entered and checked for validity.. confused about the execution..

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar oh i see.. can you answer it with some example?

Comment: You're always reassigning the argument to another list so it doesn't actually mutate the default argument list.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar, this magic 'python logic' still looks very messy from basic logic point of view..

Comment: This is a great example of the difference between a variable and an object. `var` is just a variable that references the "mutable default argument list" object. You can assign var to anything. But once you do you lose the reference to the original list. Any changes made after that do not affect the mutable argument list.

Comment: Make var as global variable you made it as local within a method so every time you call foo it will be initialized to empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rewrite your example so that we make some change to the argument before reassigning:

```
In [262]: def foo(var=[]): 
     ...:     var.append(1)   # 1
     ...:     print(var)      # 2
     ...:     var = []        # 3
     ...:     return var      # 4
     ...:                                                                            

In [263]: foo()                                                                      
[1]
Out[263]: []

In [264]: foo()                                                                      
[1, 1]  # reflects the append from the previous call
Out[264]: []
```

The append step in line 1 mutates the default argument list. The reassignment step in line 3 simply reassigns the variable `var` to a new list (a completely different object), that's what you return.

You'll see each subsequent call modifies the default argument list, it's still there but you just don't see it because you lose the reference to it when you reassign.

I recommend reading [this article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

`var=[]` on line 1 gets evaluated once when the function is defined

`var=[]` on line 3 gets evaluated every time you pass a var with `len(var) == 0`, for instance when you pass no args and the default is used.

This means that the `[]` on line 3 is a new list every time the function is called, as that line of code is executed every time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

alright, so the two things:

1. `var` in your function definition is assigned to an empty list i.e `[]` that is good,
2. `var` in the `if` statement is again being re-assigned but is the same thing, an empty list, this you don't really need as it's preventing you from achieving `[1,1]`

this may help clear things of why you're "expecting" a `var = [1,1]` the first time around:

```
 def foo(var=[]):
    if len(var) == 0:
       print(var)

    var.append(1)
    return var

print(foo()) # returns [],[1]

print(foo()) # returns  [1,1] this list appended another 1 in because when you ran this instance of foo, this list was not empty anymore rather filled with 1 and bypassed the if statement and appended another 1 resulting to [1,1]
```

thus, you don't really need that `var = []` in the if statement as it confuses the next steps as to what you want to achieve...

hope that helps somewhat :)